# Selenium NetworkConditions and ApplicationCache Exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am encountering below selenium web driver exception. My gut feeling is they are Web driver .Net Nuget package and chrome driver compatibility issue.

Driver Exceptions:

```
NetworkConditions = '((OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver)_driver).NetworkConditions' threw an exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException'
ApplicationCache = '((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver)_driver).ApplicationCache' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Versions I am using are:

```
<package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />

chromedriver_75.0.3770.8.exe

browser  Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Is there a place I can verify this compatibility? Above errors could be due to some other matter

Comment: Selenium 3.0.0 is ancient, update to 3.14.0

Comment: @Guy I was `3.14` before and had the same issue

Comment: I saw a question sometime ago about Selenium from nuget. The problem was the OP used the wrong package. Don't remember details, sorry. I'm sure however you shouldn't use version 3.0.0 with chromedriver_75.